# Why is BitmapData.copyPixels allocating memory?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have two BitmapData objects A and B and am copying a rectangle from A to B. But this is apparently leaking memory (checked this with Adobe Scout). But I don't understand why is memory being allocated when you are just copying data between two existing arrays. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

`copyPixels` is not a memory pointer to the original data, but is literally writing the same data in two locations in memory.  You can prove this by editing the bitmap data in object A after copying it to Object B, and find that Object B's data is unaffected.

Ergo, to the extent that Flash Player uses dynamic memory allocation for the environment to run, so also your `Bitmap.copyPixels` requires a memory allocation in the runtime to function.